# Topmost-left or top-leftmost?

Tags: terminology, adjective-phrases

I am confused which term is correct. I was going to say to my friend

> See the topmost-left opened tab (as in browser).

Then I realized why not say `top-leftmost`. Can I also say `leftmost-top` or `left-topmost`?
Which is the right phrase to use?

Comment: I would just say *top left*. Related; *['upper-left corner' or 'top-left corner'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123050)*

Comment: choster, that's a good point. You should post it as an answer. It would be the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is probably due to the word 'most'. Agreed to choster that you should use *top left* to refer the place. I just tried (and it came out very funny though!) something that might be still useful.

[image]

Note: the scale is approximately.

Since *topmost leftmost* will really sound weird, to avoid ambiguity, use *top-left* as here in the figure is *top right*.